# How to change the color of RadGridView header in C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, radgridview

I'm working on WinForms project. I need to change color of radGrid header from blue to green. every thing that I found, is about Web not Windows Forms.

Can any one please tell me how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres what I use for what its worth.

in code objects edit like
this.rgDailyResults.HeaderStyle =color.green or else you have tags in web and forms that control them like so:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgScenarioRollUps" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="False" Width="100px" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" Skin="">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="propGridHeader" />
    <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="propDarkGrid" />
    <ItemStyle CssClass="propLightGrid" />
    <SelectedItemStyle CssClass="propSelected" />
```

*Edit*
This is what you wanted from telerik

http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/

http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-styling-and-appearance-changing-the-currentrow-indicator.html

the latter link explains changing the "header image"

Comment: The "HeaderImage" was actually helpful, in a pinch. I know there is an event somewhere that you can override on a custom class that inherits from the default grid column type.  .. however, in Winforms it is trivial to create a System.Drawing image, fill this with a color (with Graphics, or LockBits), and set this image to the HeaderImage. So for now I was able to just assign HeaderImage = MakeMyImage(w,h,MyColors.MyGreen);

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
GridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Purple;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**C#**

```
protected void radGrid_ItemDatabound(object sender, GridItemDataBoundEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridHeaderItem)
    {
        var item = e.Item as GridHeaderItem;
        item.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

**ASPX:**

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="radGrid" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="radGrid_ItemDatabound">
[...]
</telerik:RadGrid>
```